# Show this function is 1-1

Tags: functions

The question is to show that the function $\phi$ given by $\phi(\lambda)=\frac{\lambda}{1+|\lambda|}$ is 1-1 on the complex plane. I would be grateful for a hint on how to start.

Comment: The easiest way would be to give the inverse function. If $w=\phi(z)$, then $w$ is a multiple of $z$ with a positive real factor. So to compute the inverse, set $z=aw$ with $a>0$ and try to find $a$ from $w=\phi(aw)$. Note that you have to characterize the image of $\phi$ first.

Comment: Characterizing $\phi$- in terms of where it takes concentric circles in the complex plane- helped instantly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $\lambda = r e^{i \theta}$ and  $\mu = s e^{i \psi}$ with $r=|\lambda |$ etc.,

then $\phi(\lambda) = \dfrac{r e^{i \theta}}{1+r} =\left(1-\frac{1}{1+r}\right) e^{i \theta}$ and  $\phi(\mu) = \left(1-\frac{1}{1+s}\right)  e^{i \psi}$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\phi(\lambda) = \phi(\mu)$. First show that $\lambda$ and $\mu$ must have the same argument. Then show that they have the same modulus.